# How do I pass razor counter into onkeyup javascript function

Tags: javascript, razor, model-view-controller

I have my view like so on my .cshtml page:

```
@{ var counter = 0; } 
@foreach (var item in Model){    
     @Html.TextBox("name_" + @counter, item.name, 
          new { 
               @class = "form-control", 
               @onkeyup = "myFuncWithRazorCounter('My Counter: ' + @counter)" 
          })
     { counter = counter + 1; }
}    

@section scripts
{
     <script type="text/javascript">
          function myFuncWithRazorCounter(counter){ 
               var myCounter = counter; 
               console.log(myCounter);
          }
     </script>
}
```

Let's say my Model count is 10.

When I call the function from the onkeyup event listener by typing into the textbox id of name_8, how can the counter get passed through and into myFuncWithRazorCounter() function?

End result I would like to see in the console is: My Counter: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be getting a `Invalid or unexpected token` error in the browser, and if you inspect the html you are generating, then you will see that you are rendering

```
<input ... onkeyup="myFuncWithRazorCounter('My Counter: ' + @counter)" ... >
```

Note that `@counter` is not replaced with the actual value of `counter`.

You could solve this using

```
@Html.TextBox("name_" + counter, item.name, new
{
    @class = "form-control",
    @onkeyup = "myFuncWithRazorCounter(" + counter + ")",
})
```

Note the `@` is not required. Then modify the script to

```
function myFuncWithRazorCounter(counter) { 
   var myCounter = counter; 
   console.log('My Counter: ' + counter);
}
```

As a side note, you are generating `name` attributes that have no relationship to your model, and will not bind to your model when you submit the form. To understand how to generate form controls for a collection, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to my question.  The **name_** is to identify the text box as a separate id. In the `@foreach{}` loop, there are bootstrap modals for updating.  Each loop produces a new bootstrap update modal.  The counter is used to separately identify. Thus, there are 10 modals and each modal has the `@Html.TextBox()` with the `@onkeyup = "myFuncWithRazorCounter(counter)"`.  If we disregard how the form is submitted, when it comes to `@onkeyup = "myFuncWithRazorCounter(" + counter + ")"`, can this be done: `@onkeyup = "myFuncWithRazorCounter('My counter: ' " + counter + ")"`? Thks

Comment: No (did you trying it?) It needs to be as I showed. But why are you polluting your markup with behavior - its the 21st century - use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: And to generate `form` controls for a collection, you use a `for` loop, not a `foreach` loop (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for an explanation

Comment: After giving it a whirl, I got it working by doing a tweak.  Check it out: '@onkeyup = "myFuncWithRazorCounter('My counter: " + @counter + "')"'

Comment: Again. You do not need the leading `@`.